# Where am I going wrong on this poker math problem?

Tags: probability, poker

**Someone gives you two dice. They offer to pay you \$37 if you roll two 6s. However, it will cost you \$1 a roll. What is the EV of this wager?**

My work:

> 1/36 = 35:1 = 0.0277 for \$37 = 1.027
>
> 35/36 = 1:35 = 0.972 for -\$1 = -0.972
>
> EV: 0.055

This is what the answer page shows:

> 1/36 = .028
>
> Other rolls: 35/36 = 0.972
>
> .028(\$36) + 0.972(-\$1) = x
>
> \$1.008 – \$0.972 = \$.036
>
> EV = \$0.036

I've stared at this for an hour now and I can't figure out why my answer differs. Please take me out of my misery!

Comment: In the first calculation, your payout in the positive case isn't $\$37$, it's $\$36$, since your dollar is forfeit.

Comment: We assume that the game goes as follows. You pay $\$1$ up front. If you roll a double six, you get $\$37$. Otherwise, you get nothing.
Perhaps it is simplest to look at gross winnings first. These are $37$ with probability $\frac{1}{36}$ and $0$ with probability $\frac{35}{36}$. So the expected gross win is $37\cdot \frac{1}{36}$, which is approximately $1.02778$. The expected net win is therefore approximately $0.02778$. The answer page has an arithmetical error.

Comment: ^The answer page rounded $\dfrac{1}{36} \approx 0.028$, and then calculated $\dfrac{1}{36} \cdot \$36 \approx 0.028 \cdot \$36 = \$1.008$. :( Also, how is this a poker math problem?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. You're all right, but there was only 1 answer for me to upvote. @JimmyK4542 Ah, it came from "Poker Math That Matters" by Owen Gaines, out of context it doesn't have any relation to poker. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You multiplied .0277 * 37.

The solution multiplied it by 36 (you need to pay 1 dollar). Plus the solution rounded 0.0277 to 0.028.

UPDATE: You assumed that the payout would be 37 dollars. However, you have to pay 1 dollar. So the net payout is 36 dollars.